# How to open wanted tab in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to open existing tab by ID in chrome extension? because now i'm creating new tab and after some time I need to close it and open the tab that I was before..

```
 //I save current tab id here and then execute script below

 chrome.tabs.create({ url: x.url }, tab => {
     window.setInterval(() => {
         this.productService.getUserInfo().subscribe(() => {
             this.router.navigate(['parsing']);
             chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, () => {
                 //Open the previous tab
             });
             }, error => {});
     }, 1000 * 10);
 });
```

Comment: Is the tab you wanna reopen closed at all? From the question I get it is not closed. If so, you just need to set the old tab to active `chrome.tabs.update(savedTabId, { active: true })`.

Comment: @Granga thanks, that worked!